# ios download video pause/continue

Tags: ios, video, nsurlconnection

I'm downloading a video in the background of my app. If the user restarts the app / device during the download, is there any way to continue the download from where they left off next time they start the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That mostly depends on the configuration of the file-server (HTTP, FTP, ...).

Now assuming that you are using HTTP for the download, your server needs to support the `CONTENT-RANGE` header. See [the HTTP 1.1 specification on that subject](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) for more.

See this article on the subject: [Resuming large Downloads with NSURLConnection](http://nachbaur.com/blog/resuming-large-downloads-with-nsurlconnection)

Comment: Let's assume the server supports that header. What's the magic after that?